# Not able to re-size one of the Infragistics XamDataGrid Column

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics, xamdatagrid

In my MVVM application, I am not able to resize a column (Projects). Rest all the columns are re-sizable but not the Projects column. I have used an Infragistics XamDataGrid control.

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid x:Name="ItemSource" DataSource="{Binding ItemSource,Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" AutoFit="true">
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.ViewSettings>
        <igDP:GridViewSettings/>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.ViewSettings>

    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
        <igDP:FieldSettings  LabelTextAlignment="Left" AllowRecordFiltering="true" FilterOperandUIType="ExcelStyle" FilterStringComparisonType="CaseInsensitive" FilterOperatorDefaultValue="Contains"
                       LabelClickAction="SortByOneFieldOnlyTriState" SortComparisonType="Default"/>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings  DataErrorDisplayMode="ErrorIconAndHighlight" SupportDataErrorInfo="RecordsAndCells" SelectionTypeRecord ="Single"                                
              AutoGenerateFields="False" FilterUIType="FilterRecord"/>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
    <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
        <igDP:FieldLayout>
            <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                <igDP:Field Name="IsSelected" Label=" " HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  Width="Auto" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                        <igDP:FieldSettings DataItemUpdateTrigger="OnCellValueChange">
                            <igDP:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:LabelPresenter}">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" Content=""/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </igDP:FieldSettings.LabelPresenterStyle>
                        </igDP:FieldSettings>
                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                </igDP:Field>
                <igDP:Field Label="DCS" Name="IsDCS" Converter="{StaticResource boolToStringConverter}" AllowEdit="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Width="Auto">
                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                        <igDP:FieldSettings EditAsType="sys:String"/>
                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                </igDP:Field>
                <igDP:Field Label="Projects" Name="ProjectName"  AllowEdit="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Width="*"/>
                <igDP:Field Name="IsDisplay" Label="Display" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Width="Auto">
                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                        <igDP:FieldSettings CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource buttonInCellStyle}" />
                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                </igDP:Field>
            </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
        </igDP:FieldLayout>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
</igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

Comment: Set the Width to Auto instead of *?

Comment: @mm8: I have already tried that, but did not find it re-sizing the column.

Answer (score 0):

Because of all fields, except the `Project`,  have `Width="Auto"` setting the `Project` field to `Width="*"` prevents it from resizing. To enable resizing of this field it is necessary just remove the width setting in this column.

```
 <igDP:Field Label="Projects" Name="ProjectName"  AllowEdit="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" />
```